# fetch only related values of hashtags from name in search functionality

Tags: java, mysql, postgresql, search, hashtag

I am working in java and postgresql.
I have one table name 'videos' and one of the field in it name 'video_name', so the video name can contain the #tag values like for ex.

1. my fav star `#tom`
2. enjoyed weekend `#friends#party` masti
3. had dinner at `#seefood` with `#friends`
4. walk with `#friendsEnjoy`

so now in this case i want to have search on this field 'video_name' with only hashtags. if i search for #friends i will get the number 2,3 videos.

i wanted to know what should be query in this case

i have tried using query

```
select * from videos where video_name ilike '%#Friends'
```

but it is not giving me exact results.

I have also tried using this query

```
 select * from videos where video_name ~* '#friends'
```

but using above query i got 3 results 2,3,4. and i want only 2 & 3.

/*******************************ANSWER***********************************/

Here is the answer of the above question. thanks @Alex
videos which include hashtag with space ahead of the string and again new #tag ahead of that string.

```
SELECT * 
FROM videos
WHERE lower(video_name) SIMILAR TO '%#friends(\s%|\#%)?'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM videos 
WHERE video_name REGEXP '#friends'
```

and [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3bbd0/1) is postgresql version if you need:

```
SELECT * 
FROM videos
WHERE video_name SIMILAR TO '%#friends%'
```

and [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/86483/1) is example how to resolve case sensitiveness

```
SELECT * 
FROM videos
WHERE lower(video_name) SIMILAR TO '%#friends%'
```

**EDIT** And [another variant](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/26bf6/3) with space check:

```
SELECT * 
FROM videos
WHERE lower(video_name) SIMILAR TO '%friends(\s%|\#%)?'
```

Comment: have you checked my updated question. the result what i excepting. As per your answer first it is case sensitive and then if i used ilike to remove case sensitiveness, still i am not getting the result what i suppose to have. Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: as per your updated answer it does solved the case sensitivity, but again the problem is in the results which i am getting. i want to get only 2 and 3 as my result. And if i changed query to '%#friends' this then i am getting 1 result which is correct as there is only one number (3)  #friends<space> letter in the input.

Comment: thanks for sharing the latest answer i found out way from the last idea. :) i am updating the question with the answer. i need one more query for  using this ' (\#%)?'

Comment: @Kamini you are welcome, but you should better use `WHERE lower(video_name) SIMILAR TO '%friends(\s%|\#%)?'` than union. check fidlde http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/26bf6/3